# Using request-scoped bean function as action for a temporary rendered button in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I have the following basic (and maybe stupid) understanding problem in JSF:

There is one JSF page "testPage.xhtml" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<f:view>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink id="B1" value="B1" action="#{testBean.ctrl}"/>

    <h:commandLink id="B2" value="B2" action="#{testBean.ctrl}"
            rendered="#{testBean.renderB2}"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

And one backing bean "TestBean.java" :

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="testBean")
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean renderB2 = false;

    public String ctrl() {
            setRenderB2(true);

            System.out.println("ctrl() is called.");

            return null;
    }

    public boolean getRenderB2() {
            return renderB2;
    }

    public void setRenderB2(boolean renderB2) {
            this.renderB2 = renderB2;
    }
}
```

So both links have `TestBean.ctrl()` as action.

First only `B1` is rendered. Clicking `B1` causes execution of `TestBean.ctrl()` and `B2` is rendered too.

However, clicking `B2` then does **not** execute `TestBean.ctrl()`.

And this is my question: Why is the action method not executed when clicking `B2`?

Probably it is because `B2` is not rendered again.But why does that prevent the execution of the action method (called by the previously rendered `B2` link)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the `rendered` attribute is re-evaluated again during apply request values phase of the form submit. If an `UIInput` or `UICommand` component is not rendered at that point, then JSF won't apply the request values for the component. I.e. the `UIInput` component's model value will not be updated and the `UICommand` component's action will not be invoked.

Because your bean is request scoped, it's been trashed by end of the response which displays the form and a brand new one is been created by start of the request of the form submit.

You have to preserve any request scoped properties responsible for the `rendered` attribute. The easiest way is to place the bean in the view scope by marking it `@ViewScoped` and ensuring that you return `null` or `void` from action methods which should postback to the same view.

Comment: I suspected that the rendered attribute is the cause for the disappearing action call.

Comment: That's correct. My answer already elaborated that in detail. Did you understood it?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.<br>I suspected that the rendered attribute is the cause for the action call disappearing somewhere in the lifecycle.<br>But is that really logical?<br>Is that really wanted by the JSF creators?<br>In my thinking the button was rendered when it was clicked and so the action should be executed and the new value for the rendered attribute should only be used in the render response phase?<br>(sorry I had some editing problems)

Comment: You should see it as a safeguard. The enduser (read: hacker) could otherwise easily just manipulate the HTTP request parameters to invoke the button which they are not supposed to invoke by server-side restrictions on the `rendered` attribute.

Comment: Okay, I accept, but this use of the render attribute seems to be a little bit puzzling (at least to me ;-) ). I think at least this behaviour should be written out clearly in the API docs - but also possible that only overlooked it. So I'll change it to view scope. Thank you very much again!